# Huawei Y560 Gaming Specifications

Tags: huawei

Can the Pokemon Go be played on this device? I do not want to purchase it for my daughter if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

no .... the y560 is only 1gb ram... you need at minimum 2gb ram for that

Comment: Do you have any kind of prove for that limitation? I know for sure that 1 GB of  RAM does not prevent you from playing the game (running on a Galaxy S3 here)

Comment: They've updated it to work on 1gb i believe... It was always weird, The APK has always demanded a different amount than the stores, but they've got it fine tuned i believe